# wix change non secure property to secure property in patch MSP

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I discovered that one property wasn't set as "Secure" in RTM. So I changed it, like, from

```
<Property Id="MY_PASSWORD" Hidden="yes" />
```

to

```
<Property Id="MY_PASSWORD" Secure="yes" Hidden="yes" />
```

and then added it to Patch.wxs, e.g.

```
<PropertyRef Id="MY_PASSWORD" />
```

However, when I ran repair with logging enabled, MY_PASSWORD was listed not among SecureCustomProperties.

I wonder if it is possible to change it in Patch and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a patch that will change MSI table values, such as property values, but from what you said it appears that you have not actually created a real patch and applied it. It looks as if you just rebuilt the MSI and then right-clicked and used Repair and called it a patch. This doesn't do anything except repair the already-installed MSI product. It sees that the MSI you right-clicked is already installed (just as if you right-clicked the original MSI) and repairs the existing installed product. Nothing from your new MSI gets added to the system.

An actual patch, a .msp file, is created by the patch process as the delta between two MSI files, data and MSI table content. With the MSI SDK it's done with a .pcp file and msimsp.exe. You can look at these for info on creating patches with WiX:

http://trentm.com/2007/05/building-msi-patch-packages-msp-with-wix.html

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html

The simplest way to fix the problem is use the MajorUpgrade element, and upgrade the entire older product with a new MSI with higher ProductVersion, same UpgradeCode and new ProductCode.